# The Music app stopped showing album art

Tags: music, album-art

I use the Music app strictly for mp3 files on my disk, and I added "Album Art" to every song, from jpg files.  At some point yesterday, the cache got messed up (actually TimeMachine started complaining about some files) and now all the songs no longer have any art associated with them.  Moreover, when I add art manually, Music still does not display the art in playlists (i.e. in Albums view, or in Songs view when Show Artwork is set).

Any idea how I can tell Music to rebuild the art cache?

For example, here's an album where I have re-added the album cover, but it still doesn't show in the playlist.  (Sorry it comes out so big!)

[image]